# ConfigurationSection handler in different assembly

Tags: asp.net

I have a library project, assembly name: ConfigAssembly
There is a class SiteConfigurationSection.
I want to use it as ConfigurationSection handler.

in web.config:

```
<section name="SF2" type="SiteConfigurationSection,ConfigAssembly,Version=3.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
```

When I run it, I get an error:

> An error occurred creating the
>   configuration section handler for SF2:
>   Could not load type
>   'SiteConfigurationSection' from
>   assembly
>   'ConfigAssembly,Version=3.5.0.1,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume your namespace is ConfigAssembly.

You  need to define your section like this.  I doubt your assembly is at version 3.5.0.1 - but if it really is, then change the information below to reflect that.  You also need to generate a public key token, too.

This is called [Referencing a Strong-Named Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sx4kfb%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
<section name="SF2" type="ConfigAssembly.SiteConfigurationSection,
ConfigAssembly,, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=10633fbfa3fade6e " />
```